# Symfony: how to specify port and scheme using Docker?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, nginx

Encountering issues with url generation with symfony; using docker-compose to run php, nginx and postgreSQL.

The `docker-compose.dev.yml`

```
services:
    php:
        volumes:
            - '.:/srv'
        environment:
            - SYMFONY_ENV=dev

    front:
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
        ports:
            - 0.0.0.0:8080:80
        volumes:
            - ./web:/srv
            - /keys/reports.crt:/certs/domain.crt:ro
            - /keys/reports.key:/certs/domain.key:ro
```

Which correctly sets nginx, allowing me to access it at `localhost:8080` -**http 200 OK**

The issue is, that symfony and twig are not using this url correctly. e.g.

**index.html.twig**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url }}{{ asset('email/web/styles/main.css') }}?v=1">
```

Outputs, the wrong scheme and doesn't include 8080 port.

> https://localhost/email/web/styles/main.css?v=1

One suggestion, was to add these variables to `.env` file

```
SERVER_HOST=localhost
SERVER_SCHEME=http
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

However this had no effect.

The symfony `config_dev.yml` does not have anything that specifies https or a different port, the same for the base config as well.

Any ideas how to get this working, does Symfony not get the scheme from nginx?

Intellij Xdebug, shows this in **$_SERVER**

> [SYMFONY__SERVER__HOST] => localhost

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because nginx is listening on port 80 within the container which makes symfony generate the url as if the access port is also port 80.

One thing you can try is setting the `framework.assets.base_urls` to `http://localhost:8080/` within your config. This allows you to define a base URL to use for all asset urls. You should also remove the `{{ url }}` part in your twig file as the asset function will add this for you.

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_urls:
            - 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

For more information: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#base-urls

Answer (score 0):

Your `nginx` config needs to have a proper `server_name`

```
server {
    server_name _;
    server_alias myapp.dev;
}
```